# How to configure NGINX with 2 server blocks, one when accessed by IP address and one for everything else?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

The device in question has 1 IP address and pulls double duty as UniFi Controller and Pi-hole.

I hope to configure it such that UniFi Controller's landing page loads when accessed by IP address, for example, http://192.168.1.2/ and have Pi-Hole handle everything else, such as, http://pi.hole/ or a blocked domain like http://googleadservices.com/.

Comment: See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#miscellaneous_names) on `server` blocks.

Comment: Thank you! I don't know how I missed that. If you reply as an answer, I'll accept it.